# Unity and Unreal causing restarts with no BSOD

Tags: windows-10, memory, ssd, bsod, reboot

When I work in Unity or Unreal Engine on my PC, it will restart itself 30 mins or less (sometimes as little as 5 mins). There's no BSOD, even if I turn off the auto-restart checkbox. Also, no memory dump file is created.

I wasn't able to find much info on this problem online, and I'm not sure what other steps I should take to troubleshoot. The somewhat random nature of the restarts is annoying.. I don't have reliable steps to reproduce the issue aside from "mess with lighting until the machine crashes".

What I've done so far:

- Cleaned out all dust
- Ran memtest86 (5 full passes) and no errors
- Virus and spyware check
- Verified all fans are running at normal speeds

PC Specs:

- AMD Ryzen 7 8-core
- 32GB memory
- 2TB SSD storage (close to 1TB free)
- MSI X470 Gaming M7 AC motherboard
- AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
- Windows 10 Home

Please let me know if you have any ideas to help me troubleshoot. I thought about removing everything I can (hardware) and adding it back in slowly until I figure out what's crashing it, but I'm out of ideas aside from that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Display Driver Uninstaller to uninstall all graphics drivers completely, and then reinstalled the RX 5700 XT's drivers. Everything seems fine now :D